# How to find all resources loaded not over HTTPS on the website with thousands pages?

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, web, ssl-certificate

I have a site with 10k+ pages. It works over `HTTPS`
But some pages may contain third-party images and javascript loaded over `HTTP`. A few pages contains also third-party javascript loaded over `HTTPS`, but that can loads another third-party resources over `HTTP`.

**How can I check all 10k pages regularly and find pages with resourses loaded over HTTP?**

I found some [SSL checker](https://2gdpr.com/) that can do it (*Other risks of personal data breaches*). But it only checks 20 pages.

**Is there any solution or script for my 10k pages?**

Comment: have you looked into lighthouse?

Comment: My first approach would be to run `grep -R -i "http:" /var/www/` on the server www file-system.